# Android issue in Parcelable while passing to next activity

Tags: android, serialization, parcelable

i am trying to pass my own ***Message Class*** from activity to another activity
for that i am using parcelable.
while trying to pass through bundle

### Activity1 - Passing Bundle

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("FolderList", mainMP3List)); //***mainMP3List is MusicFolder object***
i.putExtras(b);
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

---

### Activity2 - Getting Bundle

```
if(b.containsKey("FolderList"))
mainMP3List = b.getParcelable("FolderList");//Error is the here (readBundle: bad magic number)
```

i cant able to access them from second activity
i am getting this error like

**Bundle : readBundle: bad magic number**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MusicFolder implements Parcelable{

private ArrayList<SongsNameList> songsList=new ArrayList<SongsNameList>();  
private ArrayList<MusicFolder> listOfFolders=new ArrayList<MusicFolder>();


public ArrayList<SongsNameList> getSongsList() {
    return songsList;
}

public void addSongInList(SongsNameList song) {
    this.songsList.add(song);
}

public ArrayList<MusicFolder> getListOfFolders() {
    return listOfFolders;
}
public void addFolderInList(MusicFolder folder) {
    this.listOfFolders.add(folder);
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    //dest.writeString(category);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelableArrayList("songs", songsList);
    b.putParcelableArrayList("folders", listOfFolders);
    dest.writeBundle(b);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<MusicFolder> CREATOR = 
        new Parcelable.Creator<MusicFolder>() { 
    public MusicFolder createFromParcel(Parcel in) { 
        MusicFolder category = new MusicFolder();
        //category.listOfFolders = in.readString();
        Bundle b1 = in.readBundle(SongsNameList.class.getClassLoader());        
        category.songsList = b1.getParcelableArrayList("songs");

        Bundle b2 = in.readBundle(MusicFolder.class.getClassLoader());        
        category.listOfFolders = b2.getParcelableArrayList("folders");

        return category;
    }

    @Override
    public MusicFolder[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MusicFolder[size];
    }
};



  }
```

Comment: And how about `SongsNameList` is it parcelable too?

Comment: ya that is also parcelable only if i check that one separately its working fine

Comment: Could you post `readBundle: trace = ...` from logcat? It should be just after `bad magic number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested it but I think instead of:

```
    Bundle b1 = in.readBundle(SongsNameList.class.getClassLoader());        
    category.songsList = b1.getParcelableArrayList("songs");

    Bundle b2 = in.readBundle(MusicFolder.class.getClassLoader());        
    category.listOfFolders = b2.getParcelableArrayList("folders");
```

should be something like:

```
    Bundle b = in.readBundle(SongsNameList.class.getClassLoader());        
    category.songsList = b.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
    category.listOfFolders = b.getParcelableArrayList("folders");
```

Comment: Yup, that should be the case.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by you writing values / types into your Parcelable in a certain order and reading it out in different order (One of your data boundaries is being violated).

Check out your save/load order and if you don't see a problem post the code which is applicable to your `Parcelable` implementation for us to look over.

Comment: He already added parcelable code. Either way the issue is that he writes a single Bundle (with two arraylist) but reads two bundles out.

Comment: ... No he hasn't added the Parcelable code... If his problem was that the `setExtras()` was overwriting the bundle the code wouldn't fire in `getParcelable()` because he has a check for the key directly previous.